# PHP Regex remover atributos IMG e mudar SRC

Tags: php, regex, dom

Tenho a seguinte `string` com o `html`:

```
teste = "<img src="image/teste.jpg" alt="" width="32" height="32">
<p>teste</p>
<img src="image/teste2.jpg" alt="" width="132" height="132">";
```

Gostaria de um expressão regular que removesse os atributos, deixando somente o `src` e acrescentando ao conteúdo do `src` um domínio de todas as imagens da string, ficando assim:

```
teste = "<img src="http://meudominio.com/image/teste.jpg">
<p>teste</p>
<img src="http://meudominio.com/image/teste2.jpg">";
```

Lembrando que essa `string` não vai vir sempre nessa ordem, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depois de fazer alguns testes consegui fazer uma solução, segue o link online = http://www.regexr.com/3bkaa

O código em `php` ficou assim:

```
$html = preg_replace('#<img.+?src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>#i', '<img src="http://meudominio.com/$1">', $html);
```

Comment: interessante. inteligente solução